# Dealing with IEC and NEC wiring color code in the same equipment

Tags: wiring, cables, iec, color, nec

I am dealing with IEC and NEC standards for wiring color codes.

For the first time, I have to integrate european (and UL certified) COTS products - power supplies - into a system for the US market. Those COTS components are provided with some length of cables with "IEC" color code (brown : hot, blue : neutral for AC ; red : positive, black : negative for DC).

I also have to comply with NEC color code for the rest of the system (black/grey for hot/neutral and [I am not even sure], blue/white-blue for DC).

How am I suppose to deal with this ? I have both of the standard in the same equipement. What am I suppose to do between european products which are pre-wired with european color code and the rest of the system that should comply the NEC color code ?

Is my system suppose to be some kind of a rainbow ?

Thanks !

Comment: `I also have to comply with NEC color code for the rest of the system`... Why? Who exactly is the stakeholder here? Is this a consumer unit? If so, then perhaps I can see why it might be confusing for a consumer to have different wire colors. Otherwise, can't you just provide installation instructions that specify which wire color is what?

Comment: Afaik, NEC cares about wiring in buildings, not wiring in appliances. The only requirement the NEC has I'm aware of for appliances is that the appliance be 'listed' with a NRTL like UL, ETL, etc and that installation of the appliance must follow the manufacturer's instructions (included in the NRTL listing procedure). So if UL or ETL has reviewed your appliance with its IEC colored wires and your installation instructions which describe what to do with those wires, then you're in the clear as far as NEC is concerned.

Comment: @Colin : It is some kind of a metalic case with a camera in it. It is intended to be sold to the industrial market, not consumer one. I can (and actually I have to) provide installation instructions.

Comment: @brhans : No NRTL have reviewed my appliance yet (actually my customer will deal with this).
If I understand well, this is not because I don't respect NEC color wiring chart that  my equipement won't pass the 'UL laboratory' certficiation ?

Comment: @vionyst internally to your appliance you can use whatever color wire insulation you like. You can even use the same color for everything. In the end it'll come down to UL approving your instructions for installing the appliance - so even if the wires are all the same color you terminate them at some clearly marked/differentiated terminals or something.